# Interactive Dictionary, TypeError: 'dict' not callable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
import json

data = json.load(open("files1\data.json"))

def definitioner(w):
    return data(w)

word = input("Enter the word you are looking for: ")
print(definitioner(word))
```

I am doing a course on UDEMY and after trying it myself it didn't work so I even copied the code to see if it was my code, couldn't figure out what the issue was, any help would be appreciated. I am running Python 3.8
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `data(w)` like it's a function, but `data` is a dictionary. Use `data.get(w)` instead:

```
def definitioner(w):
    return data.get(w)
```

That also allows you to specify what you would like returned by default if the word is not present, by adding a second argument:

```
def definitioner(w):
    return data.get(w, 'Word not found!')
```

Comment: aaahaa thank  you very much

Comment: Happy to help! Don't forget to mark this as accepted so folks know this answer resolved your original question